# Flutter wait until initState() completes

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a Widget which renders the AppBar of my app, and it uses a custom class named Week:

```
 class Week {
  DateTime date;
  late Map<dynamic, dynamic> wSettings;

  Week({required this.date}){
    setSettings();
  }

  setSettings() async {
    String file = await rootBundle.loadString('data/weekSettings.json');
    Map decoded = jsonDecode(file);
    wSettings = decoded;
  }

  List<dynamic> customWeek(){
    return wSettings['customWeek'];
  }

  String weekdayName(int i) {
    List<dynamic> cWeek = customWeek();
    return cWeek[i];
  }

  List<dynamic> scheduleForDay(int i){
    List<dynamic> scheduleForDay = wSettings['weekSchedule'][i];
    if (scheduleForDay.isNotEmpty){
      return scheduleForDay;
    }
    return [];
  }

  // Map<int, List<dynamic>> scheduleForWeek() {
  //   Map<int, List<dynamic>> scheduleForWeek = {};
  //   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  //     scheduleForWeek[i] = scheduleForDay(i);
  //   }
  //   return scheduleForWeek;
  // }

  List<DateTime> lessonsTimeSchedule() {
    List<DateTime> output = [];
    List<dynamic> lessonsTimeSchedule = wSettings['lessonsTimeSchedule'];
    for (int i = 0; i < lessonsTimeSchedule.length; i++){
      int hour = lessonsTimeSchedule[i][0];
      int minute = lessonsTimeSchedule[i][1];
      DateTime tempTime = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, hour, minute);
      output.add(tempTime);
    }
    return output;
  }
```

The thing is that in the constructor method I execute an async function which loads data from a json file. In my widget I initialize the late variable `week` with the type `Week` and then provide it some data in the `initState()`:

```
class TopBar extends StatefulWidget {
  // const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TopBarState createState() => _TopBarState();
}

class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  late Week week;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      week = Week(date: DateTime.now());
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    now = DateTime.now();
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1),
      child: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 255, 173, 0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(40)),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromRGBO(119, 255, 173, 1),
                    Color.fromRGBO(141, 251, 255, 1)
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    vertical: 10),
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat('EEEE').format(now),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 70,
            child: Container(
              height: 171,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        offset: Offset(0, 5))
                  ]),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                child: weekScheduleContainer(week: week, now: now),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm dealing is that when I hot restart my app, the widget builds faster than the initState defines the variable week. As result for about half a second I get `LateInitializationError: Field 'wSettings' has not been initialized.`, after that the widget runs normally. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Do you need the  --WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { .... }); -- What happens to your code if you remove it?

Comment: When I delete it - same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Provider API in your TopBar widget (e.g. in its build() function) to read/watch the async returned Week data. Then you avoid explicitly assuring Flutter that the Week late init always works.

Comment: Could you be more specific please, I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you cannot cause `build()` (and what it calls, including other `build()`) to wait.  You *must* have *something* to show, up to 60 times a second.  Consider a `FutureBuilder`/`StreamBuilder` for showing different things based on async values.